# How can I reverse this triangle? The intention is to make a rhombus

Tags: python

This code prints a triangle. I now need to invert it to form a diamond.

```
n=int(input("ingrese numero de lineas "))  /*number of lines*/
caracter=str(input("ingrese un caracter"))  /*character to print*/
def triangulo(caracter, n):   
    ancho = n*len(caracter)*2
    for i in range(1,n*2+1,2):
        print ('{0}'.format(caracter*i).center(ancho))
triangulo(caracter, n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to print the diamond

```py
def triangulo(caracter, n):   
    ancho = n*len(caracter)*2
    for i in range(1,n*2+1,2):
        print ('{0}'.format(caracter*i).center(ancho))
    for i in range(n*2-3,0,-2):
        print ('{0}'.format(caracter*i).center(ancho))

triangulo(caracter, n)
```

The second loop prints the character in decreasing order
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @AlexRivé can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that?